# Where can I find the PYMSSQL Module with a .py extension?

Tags: python, python-2.7, cmd, package, pymssql

I am looking for PYMSSQL to interact with a MS SQL Server on a remote location.  This is very irritation because I previously installed PYMSSQL (found online in .py format), but cannot find it anymore.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I have Windows 7 enterprise, Python 2.7.10 and I prefer to install modules in the CMD prompt.  Pip is automatically installed in this version (I believe), so trying the following in the folder where python is stored.

```
python pip install pymssql
```

I do not even have the file, so obviously that would help :)

Thank you!
p

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? install `pymssql`?

Comment: yes, I cannot find it anywhere

Comment: This question is very confused. Why do you think you need the library in a ".py format"? Why do you think doing `pip install` would not actually install the library? That is what it's for; you don't need the file already.

Comment: pip install downloads relevant library files from internet, and installs it. You need not have them in your system,though that is a way as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

install with

```
python -m pip install pymssql
```

if it's already installed, it would show.

Comment: after that, it says, "You are using pip version 7.0.1, however version 7.1.2 is available.  You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrage pip' command."

Comment: the -m I'm sure means module?

Comment: would you recommend updating?

Comment: @Phil yes, `-m` is for module.

Comment: for any software, always update if it doesn't break things.

Comment: What would be the proper command to update based on the response?

Comment: I went into the IDE and typed import pymssql, and it went to the next line.  This should mean it is already installed?  Sorry I'm sort of new to this.

Comment: `python -m pip install -U pip` will update. yes, no `ImportError` means it's installed correctly.

Comment: man, you are good.  Thank you for the quick responses.  Updated successfully

Comment: update:  Now it says "Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pymssql in c:/xxxx.xxx.xxxx.libsite-packages

Comment: that means `pymssql` is already installed. why did you try to install it again?

Comment: I believe my issue was that, I thought it would have to be bootstrapped or downloaded via internet.

Comment: you've already accepted the answer. that's all what a question requires. glad to help

Comment: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pymssql    -This is the route I went (which was incorrect).  All I found were .whl and egg files.  Thank you so much.  Have a great day.

Comment: there were a lot of outdated pymssql links after it was included in the 2.7 release